# Session Not Working to show data

Tags: c#, asp.net

My session does not working well. I tried to get the current user's record to be view to them using session in login page, but it showed nothing. This is my line of code that might give u a clue bout my prob.

```
 protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["username"] = Login1.UserName;
}
```

The page should view the data in the gridview, so i set the setting of the girdview using data source by using session. But its not working at all. The gridview showed empty.

Thank you.

Comment: please paste your code about gridview

Comment: I just use the gridview wizard. I set the setting by click on the choose data source at the smart tag

Answer (score 0):

you should test session in another value, e.g int. if it's work ,that's not question of session。just use exclusive method

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
      if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
      {
           MembershipUser userinfo = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName);
           Session["username"] =userinfo.UserName;
      }
```